# XML cannot be the whole program

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

`XML cannot be the whole program` - anyone else seen this firebug error? happening when receiving remote data (json, as it were) via ajax.

If data type changed **json** to **html**, working fine.

This is my actual code in php:

I reloaded the page, once session has been expired.

```
if($action->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest())
{           
  $action->getResponse()->setContent("<script>window.location.reload();</script>");      
  $action->getResponse()->send();      
}
```

firebug displays the following error:

**XML cannot be the whole program
[Break on this error] window.location.reload();**

Comment: you need to provide some code if we're to help you figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you passing it the correct data format from the Ajax call? The error says it's something to do with XML, but you said you had it set to JSON, not XML.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the string `"<script>window.location.reload();</script>"` which does not contain JSON/JS but HTML. So the client tries to interpret the string as JSON/JS but notices that the whole script is just a single XML literal.

Comment: @RaviKhakhkhar Remove the script tags. They are not part of the JavaScript. Also the rest isn't JSON. If you really wanted to send JSON, you'd have to send something like `'"window.location.reload();"'` .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the  tags while loading in this way. Try to load the Javascript statements without using the  tags in the loaded file. e.g:

This code generates the same error, if I load it dynamically.

```
<?php
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Hi');</script>";
?>
```

This code doesn't generate any error and instead works like a charm:

```
<?php
    echo "alert('Hi');";
?>
```

This should help you out.